# Does $\sup \{x|h(x)\leq0\} = \max\{x|h(x)=0\}$ given $\sup \{x|h(x)\leq0\}$ is finite and $h$ is continous?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

> Does $\sup \{x|h(x)\leq0\} = \max\{x|h(x)=0\}$ given $\sup \{x|h(x)\leq0\}$ is finite and $h$ is continous?

I do not know whether or not it is correct. Can anyone help me? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Seems true enough. Have you tried proving it? Hint: what is $h(\sup \{x\mid h(x)\leq0\})$, and why must it be so?

Comment: Do you mean $\max\{ x\mid h(x)\le 0\}$ or $\max\{x\mid h(x)=0\}$? If the second, then the set you are maxing might be empty.

Comment: If it is empty, then sup ... is infinite.

Comment: The supremum of the emptyset it is proven to be minus infinity with respect ti the order properties of the real line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider $h(x)=-x^2$ over the interval $[-1,1]$. Then $\sup\{x\mid h(x)\le0\}=1$, whereas $\max\{x\mid h(x)=0\}=0$.

It would be different if you assume the function $h$ is defined (and continuous) over the whole real line.

Indeed, if $\sup\{x\mid h(x)\le0\}=b$, then $h(x)>0$ for $x>b$. Now prove that $h(b)=0$ and you're done. Hint: it can't be $h(b)<0$ or $b$ wouldn't be the supremum; can you exclude also $h(b)>0$?

Comment: What if $h$ is convex?

Comment: @HoanDo There's no problem, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what the domain of $h$ is I'm not sure that the max will exist. For instance, if $h(x)=\sin(x^{-1})$ defined on $(-\infty,0)$ then indeed the max doesn't exist. But I think that the intermediate value theorem will tell you that the supremums should be equal.